# React router not working //Even after following the documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, react-router-dom

So i was trying react for first time, i followed the documentation and at router dom i got stuck
When i use Switch is says "export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'" So in short my router isn't working and i want a way to make it work, also it is the latest version of react as i just made this project yesterday

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Form from './components/Form';
import Sus from './components/Sus';
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  // Switch,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="">
      <Navbar title="Sus" main="SusHome" about="SusAbout"/>
      <div className="container my-5">

      <Routes>
          <Route path="/" component={Form}/>
          <Route path="/sus" component={Sus} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you are using the latest version of react router which is v6 then in the `<Route />` it should be `element={<Form/>}` instead of `component={Form}`

Answer (score 1):

To render your components you have to pass like this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Form/>}/>
<Route path="/sus" element={<Sus/>} />
```

The documentation react-router-dom  version 6 is [this](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6).

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrading React Router V5 to V6**

If you have ever used React Router you know that we need to wrap our routes into this `<Switch>` component that makes sure that only one of these routes is loaded at the same time, instead of all matching routes. *Something like this*

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now with **V6** we changed the name from `Switch` to `Routes` and now the Routes **component** has a new prop called **element**, where you pass the component it needs to render inside this component and *be like this*

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```